# Group the near same numbers of a vector

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

I have the following vector:

```
c("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c")
```

and I would like to split its elements into several groups according to the near same value.
the result is like this:

`[[1]] ("a", "a"), [[2]]("b"), [[3]]("a", "a"), [[4]]("c", "c", "c")`

although the element of group 1 and group 3 is the same, they are not neighbor. so they belong to different group.
I try to using for loop to do it, but it is not good enough.

Comment: Use rle() function

Comment: ok, I will to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option but with `rleid` from `data.table` package

```
> split(v,rleid(v))
$`1`
[1] "a" "a"

$`2`
[1] "b"

$`3`
[1] "a" "a"

$`4`
[1] "c" "c" "c"
```

or another base R option

```
> split(v,cumsum(c(TRUE,head(v,-1)!=v[-1])))
$`1`
[1] "a" "a"

$`2`
[1] "b"

$`3`
[1] "a" "a"

$`4`
[1] "c" "c" "c"
```

Comment: sorry about that it seems like that i can only accept only one answer

Comment: @Paul No worries, I just want to show you other options for this problem

Comment: Yes that's a good feature of `data.table::rleid()` that it gives directly an output which has to be otherwise generated through `rep`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
vec <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c")

v2 <- rle(vec)

split(vec,rep(1:length(v2$lengths), v2$lengths)) 

$`1`
[1] "a" "a"

$`2`
[1] "b"

$`3`
[1] "a" "a"

$`4`
[1] "c" "c" "c"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I learn two new function.One is the rle, the other is the new usage of rep.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Please accept and upvote the answer for help of other users

Comment: ok. since I am new to stackoverflow, I have accepted the answer, but it seems like i cannot upvote it although i`d love to do it.